# how to detect an event reference leak

Tags: c#, livecharts

i'm using live chart version 0.9.7 in windows form project, the problem is i have a memory leak that i couldn't find out its source, i have a cartesianchart that didnt get GCed after its parent control had here is a simple implementation of what i did[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iVPL.jpg)

after forcing garbage collection
[immediate window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbEjV.jpg)

after garbage collection the parent control of the chart is null but the chart is still there. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with Visual Studio Profiler? you can take memory snapshots and get wich variable/properties are using most memory.

Comment: i used -net memory profiler i found an object called **sizechangedhandler** that is directly reference the chart object the problem is i didn't use this event all i know is it derives from window.froms @StefanoBalzarotti

Comment: I guess you add an event with +=, without removing old events with -=

Comment: i did remove the the event referencing the chart in the dispose method but i think is not about that event **SelcectedIndexChanged** because the publisher and subscriber have  equal lifetimes